# How remove non numeric numbers using filter String in Data Grid View?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I am trying to remove all non numeric from data view grid in VB using filter string. I am not entirely sure if this can be possible using filter string but my current code is as follows:

```
ftext &= String.Format("TRIM(mobile) LIKE '{0}{1}%'", If(optContains.Checked, "%", ""), awSQLFilterLike(fFilter.Text))
```

Please not some of the data I have in the database is like "0535723 Cyaon" etc. So how possibility an I remove non numeric numbers.

Comment: I would suggest adding another column to your `DataTable` that contains `Boolean` values that indicate whether the row should be included or not, then just loop through your `DataTable` and set that column based on the result of `Integer.TryParse`.

Comment: Yes that is one of last option to do. thanks